# How to access the count of duplicates in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have an array of data => this.allNodeSets. To this array, i find the duplicates. And now i want to find the count of duplicates. The only way to find the duplicate count is say => itemCount.ball

**Dummy code -**

```
var randomArray = ["ball", "ball", "tree", "ball", "tree", "bus", "car"];
var itemCount = {};

randomArray.forEach(function(value){
    if(value in itemCount) itemCount[value] = itemCount[value] + 1;
    else itemCount[value] = 1;
});
```

To find the count - do =>

```
 itemCount.ball
```

I am finding difficulty in finding this individual count like done above.
My Code -

**app.component.ts** - Angular2+

```
callFunctionSingleSelectedResult(){

allNodeSets = [
 ["claimIntimationRequestBody", "claimIntimationRequestHeader"],
 ["claimIntimationRequestBody", "claimIntimationRequestHeader"],
 ["claimIntimationRequestBody", "claimIntimationRequestBody"],
["claimIntimationRequestBody", "claimIntimationRequestHeader"],
 ["claimIntimationRequestBody", "claimIntimationResponseBody"],
 ["claimIntimationRequestHeader", "claimIntimationRequestBody"],
 ["claimIntimationRequestHeader", "claimIntimationRequestHeader"],
 ["claimIntimationRequestHeader", "claimIntimationResponseBody"],

 ["claimIntimationRequestBody", "claimIntimationRequestHeader"],

 ["claimIntimationRequestBody", "claimIntimationResponseBody"],
 ["claimIntimationRequestHeader", "claimIntimationResponseBody"],
]


       var duplicateResult = this.findDuplicates(this.allNodeSets);

       console.log("inside duplicates, result= ", duplicateResult);



//------------[1] count duplicates


              var itemCount = {};

              duplicateResult.forEach(function (value) {
                if (value in itemCount)
                  itemCount[value] = itemCount[value] + 1;
                else itemCount[value] = 1;


              });

              console.log("duplicateResult, forEach = count = ", 
           itemCount)

              for (var i = 0; i < duplicateResult.length; i++) {

                console.log(" individual count = ", itemCount)
              }

}


 // finding Duplicates

  findDuplicates(arr) {
    var len = arr.length,
      out = [],
      counts = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      var item = arr[i];
      counts[item] = counts[item] >= 1 ? counts[item] + 1 : 1;
      if (counts[item] > 1) {
        out.push(item);
      }
    }

    return out;
  }

  // Function duplicate ends
```

**Output -**

```
 duplicateResult = 
    [ 
    ["claimIntimationRequestBody","claimIntimationRequestHeader"],
    ["claimIntimationRequestBody", "claimIntimationRequestHeader"], 
    ["claimIntimationRequestBody","claimIntimationRequestHeader"] ,
    ["claimIntimationRequestBody","claimIntimationResponseBody"],
    ["claimIntimationRequestHeader", "claimIntimationResponseBody"] , 
    ["claimIntimationRequestHeader" "claimIntimationResponseBody"] 
    ]



    duplicate count, counter = {["claimIntimationRequestBody","claimIntimationRequestHeader"]: 3, 

["claimIntimationRequestBody","claimIntimationRequestBody"]: 1, 

["claimIntimationRequestBody","claimIntimationResponseBody"]: 1}
```

I searched the entire web but there is no other working way where i am able to determine a code that gives the count in some other way. Please help in determining a way to fetch the node count or maybe over here is there a way to fetch the node count. I am unable to do so.

**If i do this -**

```
 for (var i = 0; i < duplicateResult.length; i++) {

                console.log(" individual count = ", itemCount.duplicateResult)
              }
```

**I get error -**

```
Property 'duplicateResult' does not exist on type '{}'.
```

Reference -

[How to check if the elements in an array are repeated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126054/how-to-check-if-the-elements-in-an-array-are-repeated)

Comment: So you have duplicate `arrays`?

Comment: yes. I found out the duplicates before its count . I shall include it in my question

Comment: Eliminating duplicate arrays will not work the way you are trying right now, arrays are referenced by address so two arrays containing same elements will be different when compared for equality

Comment: You want to find the count of strings or the counts of subarray, please clarify ?

Comment: I want to find the count of subarray

Comment: You assign `duplicateResult` variable to the result of `findDuplicates` call and then, reassign it with new value. Why?

Comment: Nooo... actually it is just for reference. I display the output for the reference of xyz. Please see the first comment. It is the actual result that i get after findDuplicates

Comment: I corrected it please check

Comment: Sidenote: actually you already have duplicates count in `findDuplicates` so you just do the same work again.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var randomArray = ["ball", "ball", "tree", "ball", "tree", "bus", "car"];
var counts = {};
randomArray.forEach(function(x) { counts[x] = (counts[x] || 0)+1; });
console.log(counts)
```

this is a working example ,I hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var input= [ 
            ["claimIntimationRequestBody","claimIntimationRequestHeader"],
            ["claimIntimationRequestBody", "claimIntimationRequestHeader"], 
            ["claimIntimationRequestBody","claimIntimationRequestHeader"] ,
            ["claimIntimationRequestBody","claimIntimationResponseBody"],
            ["claimIntimationRequestHeader", "claimIntimationResponseBody"] , 
            ["claimIntimationRequestHeader", "claimIntimationResponseBody"] 
        ];
        
        var output = {};
        
        input.forEach(item => {
            // key is combination of all values of subarray  
            let key = item.join("_");
            if(!output[key]) output[key] = 0;
            output[key] +=1;
          }
        )
        console.log(output)
```