# how to find and console log duplicated values in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array and I want to find duplicated values in array and then console.log.
my array:

```
var arr = [{
id: 1,
name: "a"
},{
id: 1,
name: "b"
},{
id: 2,
name: "c"
}]
```

if ID is duplicate!

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: you mean when both id and name are duplicate? explain what duplicate is in your context

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask at SO. HINT: Show effort and code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541068/javascript-count-duplicates-within-an-array-of-objects

Comment: It was almost correct answer :/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541068/javascript-count-duplicates-within-an-array-of-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of the fact that objects in JavaScript must have unique keys:

```
var arr = [{
id: 1,
name: "a"
},{
id: 1,
name: "b"
},{
id: 2,
name: "c"
}];

var mergedData = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var data = arr[i];

  var merged = mergedData[data.id];
  if (!merged) {
    merged = [];
    mergedData[data.id] = merged;
  }

  merged.push(data.name);
}

console.log(mergedData);
```

We're using the ID as key in an object (which has to be unique) and put all corresponding `name`s into a list.

Comment: result will be something like that:
id: 1,
name: ["a","b"]

Comment: You didn't say what exactly you need in your question. Updated the code per your last comments now.