# How to group array object by properties?

Tags: javascript

How can we group array object by  properties. For example below I want to group the sample data by its `oldStockBooks.name` (see expected result at the bottom)?

Been to these following links, but I can't apply it in my scenario [stack-link-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541068/count-duplicates-within-an-array-of-objects), [stack-link-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395257/how-to-count-duplicate-value-in-an-array-in-javascript).

I have tried these code below, but it does not work as intended.

```
var counter = {};
oldStockBooks.forEach(function(obj) {
    var key = JSON.stringify(obj)
    counter[key] = (counter[key] || 0) + 1
});
```

---

Sample data:

```
const oldStockBooks = [
    {
        name: 'english book',
        author: 'cupello',
        version: 1,
        //... more props here
    },
    {
        name: 'biology book',
        author: 'nagazumi',
        version: 4,
    },
    {
        name: 'english book',
        author: 'cupello',
        version: 2,
    },
];
```

Expected result: display `name`, `author`, and `total` props only. And `total` props would be the number of duplication by book name.

```
const output = [
    {
        name: 'english book',
        author: 'cupello',
        total: 2,
    },
    {
        name: 'biology book',
        author: 'nagazumi',
        total: 1,
    },
];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on your `oldStockBooks` to build a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object. Since you want to group by `name`, the keys in the Map object can be the `name` values from your objects. When building your Map, if you come across a name that is already in your Map, you can grab the total from the object stored at that key, and create a new object with an updated total. Otherwise, if you have not seen the object yet, you can set the total to 0 (done by [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with a default: `total = 0`). Once you have your Map, you can grab the value objects from it and turn that into an array with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```js
const oldStockBooks = [{ name: 'english book', author: 'cupello', version: 1, }, { name: 'biology book', author: 'nagazumi', version: 4, }, { name: 'english book', author: 'cupello', version: 2, }, ];

const res = Array.from(oldStockBooks.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  // Grab name, author and total keys from the seen object. If the object hasn't already been seen, use the current object to grab the name and author, and default the total to 0
  const {name, author, total=0} = acc.get(obj.name) || obj;
  return acc.set(obj.name, {name, author, total: total+1}); // update the total
}, new Map).values());

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can efficiently achieve the result using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
const oldStockBooks = [
  {
    name: "english book",
    author: "cupello",
    version: 1,
  },
  {
    name: "biology book",
    author: "nagazumi",
    version: 4,
  },
  {
    name: "english book",
    author: "cupello",
    version: 2,
  },
];

const map = new Map();
oldStockBooks.forEach(({ name, author }) =>
  map.has(name)
    ? (map.get(name).total += 1)
    : map.set(name, { name, author, total: 1 })
);

const result = [...map.values()];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're close to the answer:

```
var response = {}; // here we put the itens mapped by the key (the 'name' field)
oldStockBooks.forEach(function(obj) {
    if( !response[ obj.name ] ) { // if it is the first item of this 'name'
        response[ obj.name ] = {
            name: obj.name,
            author: obj.author,
            total: 1,
        };
    } else { // else, we have one already, so lets only increment the total count
        response[ obj.name ].total += 1;
    }
});

// if need a list/array
var myBooks = [];
for(var key in response) myBooks.push( response[key] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: this assumes that you don't care if two books have the same title but are by different authors.

```js
const oldStockBooks = [
    {
        name: 'english book',
        author: 'cupello',
        version: 1,
    },
    {
        name: 'biology book',
        author: 'nagazumi',
        version: 4,
    },
    {
        name: 'english book',
        author: 'cupello',
        version: 2,
    },
];

var counter = {}
oldStockBooks.forEach((obj) => {
    var key = obj.name
    if (!counter[key]) {
      counter[key] = {
        ...obj,
        total: 1,
      }
    } else {
      counter[key].total = counter[key].total + 1
    }
});

const result = Object.keys(counter).map(key => {
  const {name, author, total} = counter[key]
  return {name, author, total}
})

console.log(result);
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/ExXBypZ?editors=0012)

Comment: it should have only two data outputs like in the expected output above. And should have 3 props only.

Comment: Ahh ok. Missed the expected output. I've updated the answer