# Count the occurrence of keys and convert the result into array of objects where each object belongs to one key and its occurrence (count)

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Example**

```
[
    { language: 'JavaScript' },{ language: 'JavaScript' },{ language: 'TypeScript' },
]
```

**SHOULD BE CONVERTED TO =**

```
[
{ language: 'JavaScript', count: 2 },
{ language: 'C++', count: 1 },
{ language: 'TypeScript', count: 1 }
]
```

**The idea is to count the frequency of each unique key in an array of objects and then instead of making the result look like**

```
{ key1: 2, key2: 1, key3: 7 }
```

The result should be an array of objects so that it can be map over and get rendered in React.JS or something like that.

```
[ { key1: 2 }, { key2: 1 }, { key3: 7 } ]
```

Comment: Where does `C++` come from? Also please post the code you've written in an effort to solve this yourself so that we can help you to debug it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count duplicates within an Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10541068/count-duplicates-within-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: My question is differing from you have given link in terms of input & output. Given sample link isn't solve my criteria. Given solutions mostly except fix input & counted output is differ from required too. @HereticMonkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to get exactly what you wanted. It applies to all inputs.  You have to pass the array & property name on which the count is calculated.

```js
const superAob = (data, victim) => {

    const obj = {};
  
    data.forEach((data) => {
        if(data.hasOwnProperty(victim)){
            if(obj[data[victim]]){
                obj[data[victim]]++;
            }
            else{
                obj[data[victim]] = 1;
            }
        }
    })
  
    let superArrayOfObjects = [];
  
    for (const key in obj) {
        superArrayOfObjects = [...superArrayOfObjects, { victim: key, count: obj[key]}];
    }
  
    return superArrayOfObjects;
}

let aob = 
[
    { framework: 'React.JS', website: 'Paypal' },
    { framework: 'React.JS', website: 'Tesla' },
    { framework: 'Angular', website: 'Google' },
    { framework: 'Vue.JS', website: 'Vue' },
    { framework: 'JavaScript', website: 'inblack67' },
]

console.log(superAob(aob, 'framework'));

aob = 
[
    { language: 'JavaScript' },{ language: 'JavaScript' },{ language: 'TypeScript' },
]

console.log(superAob(aob, 'language'));
```